# Найти несколько дат, максимально приближающихся к другим датам

Tags: mysql, sql

Даны 3 таблицы:

- `actions` с полями:

  - `ga_cid` (12345.12345, 23456.23456 и тд) — id в google analytics,
  - `datetime` (20190101, 20190102 и тд) — время совершения действия в формате текста «20190101»,
  - `source` (google, facebook и тд) — источник траффика
- `users` с полями:

  - `ga_cid`,
  - `user_id` (1, 2 и тд) — id в остальных таблицах бд,
  - `reg_date` (2019-01-01 00:00:00 и тд) — дата регистрации
- `stat` с полями:

  - `user_id`,
  - `first_pay` (2019-01-01 00:00:00 и тд) — дата первого платежа,
  - `second_pay` (2019-01-01 00:00:00 и тд) — дата второго платежа

Задача получить такую таблицу:

- `user_id` (1, 2)
- `reg_date` (2019-01-01 00:00:00, 2019-01-01 00:00:01)
- `reg_source` (google, facebook) — источник из таблицы `actions`, который по времени трекнулся максимально близко к `reg_date` (и `datetime` > `reg_date`) из таблицы `users`
- `first_pay` (2019-01-01 00:00:00, 2019-01-01 00:00:01),
- `first_pay_source` (google, facebook) — источник из таблицы `actions`, который по времени трекнулся максимально близко к `first_pay` (и `datetime` > `first_pay`) из таблицы `stat`
- `second_pay` (2019-01-01 00:00:00, 2019-01-01 00:00:01)
- `second_pay_source` (google, facebook) — источник из таблицы `actions`, который по времени трекнулся максимально близко к `second_pay` (и `datetime` > `second_pay`) из таблицы `stat`

Все мои попытки привели пока к такому варианту, который более менее работает, но т.к. там используется where, то я только одну дату могу подтянуть :(

```sql
select distinct s.user_id,
                u.reg_date,
                min(convert(a.datetime, date)) as 'reg_source',
                a.source,
                s.first_pay,
                s.second_pay

from stat s
join users u on s.user_id = u.user_id
join actions a on u.ga_cid = a.ga_cid

where s.first_pay is not null
and a.source is not null
and u.reg_date >= '2019-01-01'
and convert(a.datetime, date) between date(u.reg_date) and date(u.reg_date) + interval 1 hour

group by s.user_id

limit 100;
```

Comment: Создайте fiddle с примером наполнения таблиц, и покажите требуемый результат для таких данных. Уточните, "максимально близко" - это больше, меньше, или пофиг (лишь бы разница меньше - и если две даты отстоят одинаково, какую именно возвращать)?

Comment: @Akina сори, «максимально близко» имеется ввиду ближайшая дата к нужной, следующая прямо за ней. Т.е. datetime > reg_date

Comment: Ну тогда вообще не вижу проблемы. Коррелированный подзапрос, оконная функция, ещё одна копия таблицы - что угодно. В общем, делайте fiddle. И версию MySQL-сервера укажите.